# Comprobar un float a traves de un String

Tags: java, string, parsear, double

Estoy intendando, sin usar try-catch (no se me permite en este caso), saber si un String es subceptible a parsearse a double,pero no me acepta valores, como por ejemplo 1.80 . Este es el metodo:

```
private boolean alturaCorrecta() {
    boolean check = true;
    Character c;
    int control = 0;
    String cadena = TFAltura.getText();
    for (int i = 1; i < (TFAltura.getText().length()+1); i++) {
        c = cadena.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            if (c.equals('.') && control == 0) {
                control++;
            } else if (control == 1) {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(check){
        double valor=parseDouble(cadena);
        if (valor>1.50 && valor < 2.50){
           check=true; 
        }else{
            check = false;
            TAmensajes.setText("La altura debe estar comprendida entre 1.50 y 2.50");
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo falla?¿Te muestra algún mensaje de error? Si sí, ¿en qué línea?

Answer (score 1):

Tu detalle esta en el ciclo for para verificar la cadena, prueba de esta manera

```
for (int i = 0; i < (TFAltura.getText().length()); i++) {
    c = cadena.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
       if (c.equals('.') && control == 0) {
           control++;
       } else {
           check = false;
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @juandej18 funciona bien, y corrige tu problema inmediato de determinar correctamente que la cadena `"1.80"` se puede parsear a un `double`.

Pero, la dificultad con escribir nuestra propia lógica para este tipo de problema es que es sumamente difícil de hacerlo correctamente para todos los casos. Por ejemplo, ¿has anticipado cómo manejar los números negativos?

De modo que, centrándome en la pregunta más general e interesante de tu título: ¿cómo se puede verificar si una cadena `String` se puede parsear a un `double`?

Obviamente, todos sabemos que se puede hacer con un `try-catch` de esta manera:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("1.80"));     // true
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("-1.80"));    // true
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("Infinity")); // true
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("NaN"));      // true
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("abc"));      // false
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("23.45.67")); // false
}

private static boolean isValidDouble(String s) {
    boolean isValid = true;

    try {
        Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

[**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/JREX46077).

Pero dices que no puedes usar un `try-catch`. Y, en efecto, de ser posible, siempre es mejor evitar usar excepciones para situaciones *normales*. Por lo que no puedo creer que Java aún no incluya un método oficial que se pueda llamar para hacer esta verificación sin que te lanze una excepción. C#, por ejemplo, incluye el método `TryParse` para manejar esta situación.

Pero interesantemente, si miras en la documentación para [`Double.valueOf(s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), notarás una sección que dice (traducido):

> Para evitar llamar este método con una cadena inválida y que te lanze un `NumberFormatException`, se puede usar la expresión regular siguiente para verificar la cadena de antemano:

... y luego te suministra una larga expresión regular que puedes usar.

Así que, ya que la recomendación está en la documentación oficial, ¿por qué no usarla? De seguro funcionará mejor que escribir la lógica por nuestra cuenta.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo usarla:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("1.80"));     // true
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("-1.80"));    // true
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("Infinity")); // true
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("NaN"));      // true
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("abc"));      // false
    System.out.println(isValidDouble("23.45.67")); // false
}

private static boolean isValidDouble(String s) {
  final String Digits     = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
  final String HexDigits  = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";
  // an exponent is 'e' or 'E' followed by an optionally
  // signed decimal integer.
  final String Exp        = "[eE][+-]?"+Digits;
  final String fpRegex    =
      ("[\\x00-\\x20]*"+  // Optional leading "whitespace"
       "[+-]?(" + // Optional sign character
       "NaN|" +           // "NaN" string
       "Infinity|" +      // "Infinity" string

       // A decimal floating-point string representing a finite positive
       // number without a leading sign has at most five basic pieces:
       // Digits . Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix
       //
       // Since this method allows integer-only strings as input
       // in addition to strings of floating-point literals, the
       // two sub-patterns below are simplifications of the grammar
       // productions from section 3.10.2 of
       // The Java Language Specification.

       // Digits ._opt Digits_opt ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
       "((("+Digits+"(\\.)?("+Digits+"?)("+Exp+")?)|"+

       // . Digits ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
       "(\\.("+Digits+")("+Exp+")?)|"+

       // Hexadecimal strings
       "((" +
        // 0[xX] HexDigits ._opt BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
        "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "(\\.)?)|" +

        // 0[xX] HexDigits_opt . HexDigits BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
        "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "?(\\.)" + HexDigits + ")" +

        ")[pP][+-]?" + Digits + "))" +
       "[fFdD]?))" +
       "[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"

  return Pattern.matches(fpRegex, s);
}
```

[**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/GBU45679).

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, estaría bien que especificaras un poco mas cual es el error que te da, pegando por ejemplo el mensaje de la excepcion en caso de que lo haya.

Por otro lado, `for (int i = 1; i < (TFAltura.getText().length()+1); i++) {` es muy probable que te lanze un `IndexOutOfBoundsException` pues siempre vas a intentar buscar una posicion mas de el tamaño maximo que tenga.

Prueba a poner  `for (int i = 0; i < TFAltura.getText().length(); i++) {`

De todas formas como te he dicho, intenta especificar un pco ams el error que te da.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Tu logica esta bien. El error que te debe estar dando como dicen arriba es de un ArrayOutBound Index

```
  String cadena = TFAltura.getText();
    for (int i = 1; i < (TFAltura.getText().length()+1); i++) {
        c = cadena.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            if (c.equals('.') && control == 0) {
                control++;
            } else if (control == 1) {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Vamos por pasos una ves definido nuestro array al poner

> for (int i = 1; i < (TFAltura.getText().length()+1); i++)

Estamos diciendo que vaya un puesto mas y estoy muy seguro que debe tirar error lo dejaremos de esta forma

> for (int i = 1; i < (TFAltura.getText().length()); i++)

Asi obtenemos todo el String sin que nos genere ese error. 
Vamos al segundo paso. Si es que estamos en el ultimo digito y no encontramos una coma o punto en tu caso entonces sabemos que no es decimal

```
int last = 0;   

    for (int i = 1; i < (TFAltura.getText().length()); i++) {
            last = i + 1; 
            if(last == TFAltura.getText().length()+1)
            {
                    check = false;
                    break;
            }        
        }
```

Ya tenemos una validacion. Ahora a la siguiente validacion que pasa si te pasan un numero con

> 123.123.123

Entonces eso quiere decir que solo puede haber un punto, sino ya no seria un numero valido

```
for (int i = 1; i < (TFAltura.getText().length()); i++) {
        last = i + 1; 
        if(last == TFAltura.getText().length()+1)
        {
                check = false;
                break;
        }
    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
        if (c.equals('.')) {
            control++;
        }
        else{ // Si no es un punto entonces es una Letra y ya no es un numero
              check = false;
                break;
        } 


    }        
    }
```

Muy bien ahora sabemos que si

> control > 1 entonces el numero tiene mas de dos comas o puntos

Por ultimo retornamos nuestras variables si es falso

```
    for (int i = 1; i < (TFAltura.getText().length()); i++) {
            last = i + 1; 
            if(last == TFAltura.getText().length()+1)
            {
                    check = false;
                    break;
            }
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            if (c.equals('.')) {
                control++;
            }
            else{ // Si no es un punto entonces es una Letra y ya no es un numero
                  check = false;
                    break;
            } 


        }        
        }

  if (check == false){
return check;
}
else if (control > 1){
 return check;
}
else if(control == 1 && check == true)
{ 
        double valor=parseDouble(cadena);
        if (valor>1.50 && valor < 2.50){
           check=true; 
        }else{
            check = false;
            TAmensajes.setText("La altura debe estar comprendida entre 1.50 y 2.50");
        }
}
   return check;
```

Espero poderte guiarte en algo saludos.